# Which quantity is larger

Tags: real-analysis

How can I determine which quantity is larger. $n$ an integer, $K$ and $F$ are reals and $x^{+} = \max( x , 0)$  :

$$n\left( -K + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} F_{i} \right )^{+}$$ compared to $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-K + F_{i} ) ^{+}$$

Comment: What do you mean by the "+" exponent, and what is the relationship with linear algebra ?

Comment: the positive part. Yes I guess it's a wrong tag.

Comment: positive part of x= max(x,0) ?

Comment: I just edited the post. right

Comment: Can anyone explain this downvote ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It was mine, and I removed it as the post got better. Still, the tag doesn't seem right.

Comment: Clearer to write $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-K+F_{i})\right )^{+}$, I guess.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, I really meant $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-K + F_{i} ) ^{+}$

Comment: @RayGil It was meant instead of the _first_ expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $G_i:=F_i-K$.

The first expresssion is the sum of all $G_i$, or zero.

The second is the sum of all positive $G_i$, hence not smaller than the above.